# How to display many columns in Angular 9

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I m working on my end of study Project and after finishing my back end work i have to display a table with 19 columns with Angular.
Any idea how can i do that ? its really messy when i try to display it normally with Angular material table.

I think about merging 2 columns in 1 and display both of them in one cell but i don't know if that is doable or not.

here is the code:

```
<div style="overflow: auto;">
<div class="mat-elevation-z8" style="width: auto;">
<mat-table [dataSource]= "listData" matSort>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:displayedColumns;"></mat-row>


<ng-container matColumnDef="DEALCLASS" >
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>DEALCLASS</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.DEALCLASS}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="DEALCAT">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> DEALCAT</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.DEALCAT}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="BLOCKID">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> BLOCKID</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.BLOCKID}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="DEALID">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> DEALID</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.DEALID}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="DEALTYPE">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> DEALTYPE</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.DEALTYPE}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="TRADEDATE">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> TRADEDATE</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.TRADEDATE}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="STARTDATE">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> STARTDATE</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.STARTDATE}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="ENDDATE">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ENDDATE</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.ENDDATE}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="INSTRSHORTNAME">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> INSTRSHORTNAME</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.INSTRSHORTNAME}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="INSTRNAME">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> INSTRNAME</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.INSTRNAME}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="CPTYSHORTNAME">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> CPTYSHORTNAME</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.CPTYSHORTNAME}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="QUANTITY">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> QUANTITY</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.QUANTITY}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="SETTLECURRENCIESSHORTNAME">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SETTLECURRENCIESSHORTNAME</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.SETTLECURRENCIESSHORTNAME}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="SETTLEAMT">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SETTLEAMT</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.SETTLEAMT}}</mat-header-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="FLOATINGRATESSHORTNAME">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> FLOATINGRATESSHORTNAME</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.FLOATINGRATESSHORTNAME}}</mat-header-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="RENTSPREADFIXEDRATE">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> RENTSPREADFIXEDRATE</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.RENTSPREADFIXEDRATE}}</mat-header-cell>

</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="WORKFLOWSTATE">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> WORKFLOWSTATE</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.WORKFLOWSTATE}}</mat-header-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="FOLDERSHORTNAME">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> FOLDERSHORTNAME</mat-header-cell>
<mat-header-cell *matCellDef="let element ">{{element.FOLDERSHORTNAME}}</mat-header-cell>
</ng-container>
</mat-table>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table Design to render large amount of data Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063714/table-design-to-render-large-amount-of-data-angular)

Comment: Please provide your code. Without it we do not know what you've tried so far or where the error is.

Comment: @MichaelD i added the code. thank you for your remark.

Comment: Well i fixed this with standard approch which is CSS. I incresead my mat-header-row and mat-header-cell height and it looks good :) .